# build ffmpeg on ubuntu : build nasm fails

Tags: ubuntu, build, ffmpeg, nasm, nvenc

trying to build ffmpeg on ubuntu 18.10

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

first install dependencies

```
sudo apt-get update -qq && sudo apt-get -y install \
autoconf \
automake \
build-essential \
cmake \
git-core \
libass-dev \
libfreetype6-dev \
libsdl2-dev \
libtool \
libva-dev \
libvdpau-dev \
libvorbis-dev \
libxcb1-dev \
libxcb-shm0-dev \
libxcb-xfixes0-dev \
pkg-config \
texinfo \
wget \
zlib1g-dev
```

then make dirs

```
mkdir -p ~/ffmpeg_sources ~/bin
```

then build nasm

```
cd ~/ffmpeg_sources && \
wget https://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.13.03/nasm-2.13.03.tar.bz2 && \
tar xjvf nasm-2.13.03.tar.bz2 && \
cd nasm-2.13.03 && \
./autogen.sh && \
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" ./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --bindir="$HOME/bin" && \
make && \
make install
```

then error

```
--2019-02-04 17:45:17--  https://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.13.03/nasm-2.13.03.tar.bz2
Resolving www.nasm.us (www.nasm.us)... 2607:7c80:54:e::136, 198.137.202.136
Connecting to www.nasm.us (www.nasm.us)|2607:7c80:54:e::136|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 974491 (952K) [application/x-bzip2]
Saving to: ‘nasm-2.13.03.tar.bz2’

nasm-2.13.03.tar.bz2          100%[=================================================>] 951.65K  1.51MB/s    in 0.6s    

2019-02-04 17:45:18 (1.51 MB/s) - ‘nasm-2.13.03.tar.bz2’ saved [974491/974491]

nasm-2.13.03/
nasm-2.13.03/AUTHORS
nasm-2.13.03/TODO
nasm-2.13.03/headers/
nasm-2.13.03/headers/c
nasm-2.13.03/headers/mac
nasm-2.13.03/headers/perl
nasm-2.13.03/headers/doc
nasm-2.13.03/test/
nasm-2.13.03/test/objtest.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/float8.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/avx512cd.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/br890790_i.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/avx.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/pushseg.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/br3074517.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/inc2.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/elfso.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/br2222615.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/local.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/time.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/smartalign64.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/movimm.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/elif.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/absolute.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/nullfile.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/test67.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/reldef.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/jmp64.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/addr64x.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/weirdpaste.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/newrdwr.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/gas2nasm.py
nasm-2.13.03/test/br3104312.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/br3041451.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/xchg.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/movnti.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/br3385573.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/testdos.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/br3005117.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/pcrel.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/objexe.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/immwarn.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/smartalign16.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/floatx.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/pinsr64.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/radix.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/gotoff64.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/elf64so.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/smartalign32.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/floatize.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/lnxhello.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/bisect.sh
nasm-2.13.03/test/fpu.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/ptr.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/br2496848.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/binexe.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/gather.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/nop.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/br560575.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/uscore.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/struc.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/br3026808.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/zerobyte.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/avx005.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/riprel.pl
nasm-2.13.03/test/iftoken.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/times.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/ifmacro.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/br3392411.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/br3392418.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/riprel.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/align13.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/rdpid.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/utf.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/br3187743.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/movd.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/floatb.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/inc1.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/ilog2.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/crc32.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/org.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/popcnt.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/ifelse.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/andbyte.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/bintest.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/imm64.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/pinsr16.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/ppindirect.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/Makefile
nasm-2.13.03/test/br3392252.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/elftest64.c
nasm-2.13.03/test/hexfp.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/alonesym-obj.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/br3092924.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/br3392442.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/loopoffs.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/vex.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/bcd.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/iftoken.pl
nasm-2.13.03/test/br3189064.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/br3392439.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/cofftest.c
nasm-2.13.03/test/floatexp.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/mpx-64.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/elftest.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/avx512pf.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/xmm0.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/br3392396.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/ifenv.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/insnlbl.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/imm.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/performtest.pl
nasm-2.13.03/test/br2148476.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/imul.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/br890790.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/perf/
nasm-2.13.03/test/perf/macro.pl
nasm-2.13.03/test/perf/label.pl
nasm-2.13.03/test/perf/token.pl
nasm-2.13.03/test/br3392259.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/br3392363.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/macroerr.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/br560873.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/sreg.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/br3200749.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/xcrypt.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/br3109604.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/pragma.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/objlink.c
nasm-2.13.03/test/vaesenc.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/align13s.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/br2030823.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/imacro.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/timesneg.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/macroerr.inc
nasm-2.13.03/test/vgather.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/elftest.c
nasm-2.13.03/test/floattest.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/lar_lsl.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/expimp.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/testnos3.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/r13.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/splitea.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/mpx.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/sha.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/fwdopt.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/strlen.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/a32offs.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/vmread.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/cv8struc.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/aoutso.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/relocs.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/_version.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/br1879590.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/tmap.nas
nasm-2.13.03/test/hle.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/br2003451.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/float.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/mmxsize.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/far64.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/new
nasm-2.13.03/test/movd64.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/incbin.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/inctest.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/cofftest.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/avx512f.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/nasmformat.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/prefix66.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/paste.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/br978756.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/br3028880.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/optimization.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/aouttest.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/macro-defaults.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/pinsr32.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/br3066383.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/_file_.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/invlpga.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/incbin.data
nasm-2.13.03/test/sha-64.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/multisection.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/avx2.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/avx512er.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/dtbcd.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/pextrw.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/lwp.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/br3174983.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/changed.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/larlsl.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/riprel2.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/fwdoptpp.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/br3058845.asm
nasm-2.13.03/test/aouttest.c
nasm-2.13.03/test/br3392392.asm
nasm-2.13.03/Makefile.in
nasm-2.13.03/README
nasm-2.13.03/common/
nasm-2.13.03/common/common.c
nasm-2.13.03/autogen.sh
nasm-2.13.03/version.sed
nasm-2.13.03/version.pl
nasm-2.13.03/include/
nasm-2.13.03/include/insns.h
nasm-2.13.03/include/hashtbl.h
nasm-2.13.03/include/error.h
nasm-2.13.03/include/perfhash.h
nasm-2.13.03/include/rdoff.h
nasm-2.13.03/include/nasm.h
nasm-2.13.03/include/nasmint.h
nasm-2.13.03/include/ver.h
nasm-2.13.03/include/raa.h
nasm-2.13.03/include/md5.h
nasm-2.13.03/include/opflags.h
nasm-2.13.03/include/iflag.h
nasm-2.13.03/include/tables.h
nasm-2.13.03/include/disp8.h
nasm-2.13.03/include/rbtree.h
nasm-2.13.03/include/labels.h
nasm-2.13.03/include/compiler.h
nasm-2.13.03/include/strlist.h
nasm-2.13.03/include/nasmlib.h
nasm-2.13.03/include/saa.h
nasm-2.13.03/contrib/
nasm-2.13.03/contrib/VSrules/
nasm-2.13.03/contrib/VSrules/nasm.README
nasm-2.13.03/contrib/VSrules/nasm.rules
nasm-2.13.03/contrib/MSVC6.txt
nasm-2.13.03/SubmittingPatches
nasm-2.13.03/stdlib/
nasm-2.13.03/stdlib/strlcpy.c
nasm-2.13.03/stdlib/vsnprintf.c
nasm-2.13.03/stdlib/snprintf.c
nasm-2.13.03/stdlib/strnlen.c
nasm-2.13.03/disasm/
nasm-2.13.03/disasm/sync.c
nasm-2.13.03/disasm/disasm.h
nasm-2.13.03/disasm/ndisasm.c
nasm-2.13.03/disasm/sync.h
nasm-2.13.03/disasm/disasm.c
nasm-2.13.03/nasmlib/
nasm-2.13.03/nasmlib/md5c.c
nasm-2.13.03/nasmlib/rbtree.c
nasm-2.13.03/nasmlib/badenum.c
nasm-2.13.03/nasmlib/srcfile.c
nasm-2.13.03/nasmlib/mmap.c
nasm-2.13.03/nasmlib/zerobuf.c
nasm-2.13.03/nasmlib/crc64.c
nasm-2.13.03/nasmlib/saa.c
nasm-2.13.03/nasmlib/raa.c
nasm-2.13.03/nasmlib/bsi.c
nasm-2.13.03/nasmlib/ver.c
nasm-2.13.03/nasmlib/perfhash.c
nasm-2.13.03/nasmlib/strlist.c
nasm-2.13.03/nasmlib/hashtbl.c
nasm-2.13.03/nasmlib/filename.c
nasm-2.13.03/nasmlib/file.c
nasm-2.13.03/nasmlib/path.c
nasm-2.13.03/nasmlib/file.h
nasm-2.13.03/nasmlib/realpath.c
nasm-2.13.03/nasmlib/string.c
nasm-2.13.03/nasmlib/readnum.c
nasm-2.13.03/nasmlib/perfhash.pl
nasm-2.13.03/nasmlib/ilog2.c
nasm-2.13.03/nasmlib/malloc.c
nasm-2.13.03/LICENSE
nasm-2.13.03/ndisasm.txt
nasm-2.13.03/misc/
nasm-2.13.03/misc/c16.mac
nasm-2.13.03/misc/README
nasm-2.13.03/misc/proc32.ash
nasm-2.13.03/misc/nasmstab
nasm-2.13.03/misc/c32.mac
nasm-2.13.03/misc/Nindent
nasm-2.13.03/misc/exebin.mac
nasm-2.13.03/misc/Doxyfile
nasm-2.13.03/misc/exebin2.mac
nasm-2.13.03/misc/magic
nasm-2.13.03/misc/omfdump.c
nasm-2.13.03/misc/nasm.sl
nasm-2.13.03/misc/hints.txt
nasm-2.13.03/misc/scitech.mac
nasm-2.13.03/misc/crcgen.c
nasm-2.13.03/misc/myC32.mac
nasm-2.13.03/misc/genfma.pl
nasm-2.13.03/misc/xcrcgen.c
nasm-2.13.03/misc/fmtinsns.pl
nasm-2.13.03/misc/pmw.bat
nasm-2.13.03/CHANGES
nasm-2.13.03/configure
nasm-2.13.03/ndisasm.1
nasm-2.13.03/tools/
nasm-2.13.03/tools/tag-release
nasm-2.13.03/tools/syncfiles.pl
nasm-2.13.03/tools/cleanpatch
nasm-2.13.03/tools/cleanfile
nasm-2.13.03/tools/release
nasm-2.13.03/tools/mkdep.pl
nasm-2.13.03/INSTALL
nasm-2.13.03/install-sh
nasm-2.13.03/Mkfiles/
nasm-2.13.03/Mkfiles/README
nasm-2.13.03/Mkfiles/openwcom.mak
nasm-2.13.03/Mkfiles/msvc.mak
nasm-2.13.03/version
nasm-2.13.03/nasm.txt
nasm-2.13.03/nsis/
nasm-2.13.03/nsis/version.nsh
nasm-2.13.03/nsis/nasm-un.ico
nasm-2.13.03/nsis/NASMMultiUser.nsh
nasm-2.13.03/nsis/getpearch.pl
nasm-2.13.03/nsis/nasm.nsi
nasm-2.13.03/nsis/nasm.ico
nasm-2.13.03/macros/
nasm-2.13.03/macros/macros.pl
nasm-2.13.03/macros/standard.mac
nasm-2.13.03/macros/ifunc.mac
nasm-2.13.03/macros/altreg.mac
nasm-2.13.03/macros/macros.c
nasm-2.13.03/macros/smartalign.mac
nasm-2.13.03/macros/fp.mac
nasm-2.13.03/config/
nasm-2.13.03/config/watcom.h
nasm-2.13.03/config/msvc.h
nasm-2.13.03/config/config.h.in
nasm-2.13.03/config/unknown.h
nasm-2.13.03/nasm.1
nasm-2.13.03/asm/
nasm-2.13.03/asm/preproc.h
nasm-2.13.03/asm/preproc-nop.c
nasm-2.13.03/asm/tokens.h
nasm-2.13.03/asm/pptok.h
nasm-2.13.03/asm/stdscan.c
nasm-2.13.03/asm/nasm.c
nasm-2.13.03/asm/pragma.c
nasm-2.13.03/asm/pptok.dat
nasm-2.13.03/asm/float.h
nasm-2.13.03/asm/pptok.pl
nasm-2.13.03/asm/directiv.dat
nasm-2.13.03/asm/error.c
nasm-2.13.03/asm/labels.c
nasm-2.13.03/asm/eval.h
nasm-2.13.03/asm/directiv.h
nasm-2.13.03/asm/assemble.h
nasm-2.13.03/asm/parser.h
nasm-2.13.03/asm/assemble.c
nasm-2.13.03/asm/listing.c
nasm-2.13.03/asm/tokhash.c
nasm-2.13.03/asm/preproc.c
nasm-2.13.03/asm/exprdump.c
nasm-2.13.03/asm/pptok.c
nasm-2.13.03/asm/parser.c
nasm-2.13.03/asm/quote.h
nasm-2.13.03/asm/quote.c
nasm-2.13.03/asm/segalloc.c
nasm-2.13.03/asm/tokens.dat
nasm-2.13.03/asm/float.c
nasm-2.13.03/asm/exprlib.c
nasm-2.13.03/asm/phash.pl
nasm-2.13.03/asm/directiv.c
nasm-2.13.03/asm/listing.h
nasm-2.13.03/asm/directbl.c
nasm-2.13.03/asm/stdscan.h
nasm-2.13.03/asm/rdstrnum.c
nasm-2.13.03/asm/pptok.ph
nasm-2.13.03/asm/tokhash.pl
nasm-2.13.03/asm/strfunc.c
nasm-2.13.03/asm/eval.c
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/rdf2bin.1
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/segtab.c
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/rdf2srec.1
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/rdf2ihx.1
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/rdlib.h
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/test/
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/test/rdftest1.asm
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/test/rdtlib.asm
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/test/makelib.sh
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/test/rdftest2.asm
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/test/Makefile
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/test/rdfseg.asm
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/test/testlib.asm
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/test/rdfseg2.asm
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/test/rdtmain.asm
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/rdf2ith.1
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/rdlib.c
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/README
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/symtab.c
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/segtab.h
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/hash.c
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/ldrdf.1
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/rdfutils.h
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/rdflib.1
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/rdf2com.1
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/rdoff.c
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/ldsegs.h
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/rdfdump.1
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/rdlar.c
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/rdf2bin.c
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/symtab.h
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/collectn.c
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/rdfload.h
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/rdflib.c
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/rdfload.c
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/ldrdf.c
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/rdx.1
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/rdx.c
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/collectn.h
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/rdlar.h
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/hash.h
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/rdfdump.c
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/doc/
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/doc/Makefile
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/doc/v1-v2.txt
nasm-2.13.03/rdoff/doc/rdoff.texi
nasm-2.13.03/version.mac
nasm-2.13.03/output/
nasm-2.13.03/output/legacy.c
nasm-2.13.03/output/elf.h
nasm-2.13.03/output/outbin.mac
nasm-2.13.03/output/nulldbg.c
nasm-2.13.03/output/outform.h
nasm-2.13.03/output/stabs.h
nasm-2.13.03/output/outobj.c
nasm-2.13.03/output/codeview.c
nasm-2.13.03/output/outform.c
nasm-2.13.03/output/outlib.c
nasm-2.13.03/output/outbin.c
nasm-2.13.03/output/outieee.c
nasm-2.13.03/output/outas86.mac
nasm-2.13.03/output/outmacho.mac
nasm-2.13.03/output/outaout.c
nasm-2.13.03/output/outaout.mac
nasm-2.13.03/output/outdbg.c
nasm-2.13.03/output/outmacho.c
nasm-2.13.03/output/outrdf2.c
nasm-2.13.03/output/nullout.c
nasm-2.13.03/output/outlib.h
nasm-2.13.03/output/outobj.mac
nasm-2.13.03/output/outcoff.c
nasm-2.13.03/output/outcoff.mac
nasm-2.13.03/output/outrdf2.mac
nasm-2.13.03/output/outelf.h
nasm-2.13.03/output/pecoff.h
nasm-2.13.03/output/outrdf.mac
nasm-2.13.03/output/dwarf.h
nasm-2.13.03/output/outelf.c
nasm-2.13.03/output/outas86.c
nasm-2.13.03/output/outelf.mac
nasm-2.13.03/perllib/
nasm-2.13.03/perllib/random_sv_vectors.ph
nasm-2.13.03/perllib/gensv.pl
nasm-2.13.03/perllib/phash.ph
nasm-2.13.03/perllib/crc64.ph
nasm-2.13.03/configure.ac
nasm-2.13.03/aclocal.m4
nasm-2.13.03/ChangeLog
nasm-2.13.03/nasm.spec.in
nasm-2.13.03/x86/
nasm-2.13.03/x86/insnsi.h
nasm-2.13.03/x86/regvals.c
nasm-2.13.03/x86/insnsa.c
nasm-2.13.03/x86/insns.pl
nasm-2.13.03/x86/regs.h
nasm-2.13.03/x86/regflags.c
nasm-2.13.03/x86/disp8.c
nasm-2.13.03/x86/regdis.h
nasm-2.13.03/x86/insnsn.c
nasm-2.13.03/x86/iflag.c
nasm-2.13.03/x86/insnsb.c
nasm-2.13.03/x86/regs.pl
nasm-2.13.03/x86/regdis.c
nasm-2.13.03/x86/insns-iflags.ph
nasm-2.13.03/x86/insnsd.c
nasm-2.13.03/x86/regs.c
nasm-2.13.03/x86/iflaggen.h
nasm-2.13.03/x86/regs.dat
nasm-2.13.03/x86/insns.dat
nasm-2.13.03/nasm.spec
nasm-2.13.03/version.h
nasm-2.13.03/version.mak
nasm-2.13.03/nasm.spec.sed
nasm-2.13.03/doc/
nasm-2.13.03/doc/Makefile.in
nasm-2.13.03/doc/nasmdoc.css
nasm-2.13.03/doc/README
nasm-2.13.03/doc/findfont.ph
nasm-2.13.03/doc/pswidth.ph
nasm-2.13.03/doc/pspdf.pl
nasm-2.13.03/doc/head.ps
nasm-2.13.03/doc/rdsrc.pl
nasm-2.13.03/doc/Makefile
nasm-2.13.03/doc/ttfmetrics.ph
nasm-2.13.03/doc/genps.pl
nasm-2.13.03/doc/inslist.pl
nasm-2.13.03/doc/opt_var.txt
nasm-2.13.03/doc/nasmlogo.eps
nasm-2.13.03/doc/afmmetrics.ph
nasm-2.13.03/doc/local.css
nasm-2.13.03/doc/internal.doc
nasm-2.13.03/doc/changes.src
nasm-2.13.03/doc/nasmdoc.src
nasm-2.13.03/doc/psfonts.ph
nasm-2.13.03/doc/nasmlogw.png
+ autoheader
+ autoconf
+ rm -rf autom4te.cache config.log config.status
+ rm -f Makefile rdoff/Makefile doc/Makefile
+ rm -f config.h.in config.h config/config.h
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99... none needed
checking for gcc option to accept ISO Standard C... (cached) none needed
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for suffix of library files... a
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking for C/C++ restrict keyword... __restrict
checking for size_t... yes
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking if gcc accepts -fwrapv... yes
checking if gcc accepts -U__STRICT_ANSI__... yes
checking if gcc accepts -fno-common... yes
checking for nroff... nroff
checking for asciidoc... no
checking for xmlto... no
configure: WARNING: No asciidoc package found
configure: WARNING: No xmlto package found
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking for inttypes.h... (cached) yes
checking for strings.h... (cached) yes
checking for stdbool.h that conforms to C99... yes
checking for _Bool... yes
checking stdnoreturn.h usability... yes
checking stdnoreturn.h presence... yes
checking for stdnoreturn.h... yes
checking io.h usability... no
checking io.h presence... no
checking for io.h... no
checking fcntl.h usability... yes
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/param.h usability... yes
checking sys/param.h presence... yes
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking sys/mman.h usability... yes
checking sys/mman.h presence... yes
checking for sys/mman.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/stat.h... (cached) yes
checking for strcasecmp... yes
checking for stricmp... no
checking for strncasecmp... yes
checking for strnicmp... no
checking for strsep... yes
checking for strnlen... yes
checking for getuid... yes
checking for getgid... yes
checking for realpath... yes
checking for canonicalize_file_name... yes
checking for _fullpath... no
checking for pathconf... yes
checking for _LARGEFILE_SOURCE value needed for large files... no
checking for _fseeki64... no
checking for ftruncate... yes
checking for _chsize... no
checking for _chsize_s... no
checking for fileno... yes
checking for _fileno... no
checking for _filelengthi64... no
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/param.h... (cached) yes
checking for getpagesize... yes
checking for working mmap... yes
checking for getpagesize... (cached) yes
checking for sysconf... yes
checking for access... yes
checking for _access... no
checking for faccessat... yes
checking for __builtin_clz... yes
checking for __builtin_clzl... yes
checking for __builtin_clzll... yes
checking for __builtin_expect... yes
checking for vsnprintf... yes
checking for _vsnprintf... no
checking for snprintf... yes
checking for _snprintf... no
checking for strlcpy... no
checking for struct _stati64... no
checking for struct stat... yes
checking for stat... yes
checking for _stati64... no
checking for fstat... yes
checking for _fstati64... no
checking whether strcasecmp is declared... yes
checking whether stricmp is declared... no
checking whether strncasecmp is declared... yes
checking whether strnicmp is declared... no
checking whether strsep is declared... yes
checking whether strlcpy is declared... no
checking whether strnlen is declared... yes
checking for uintptr_t... yes
checking if gcc accepts -Werror=attributes... yes
checking if gcc supports the noreturn function attribute... yes
checking if gcc supports the returns_nonnull function attribute... yes
checking if gcc supports the malloc function attribute... yes
checking if gcc supports the alloc_size function attribute... yes
checking if gcc supports the format function attribute... yes
checking if gcc supports the const function attribute... yes
checking if gcc supports the pure function attribute... yes
checking if gcc supports the error function attribute... yes
checking if gcc accepts -W... yes
checking if gcc accepts -Wall... yes
checking if gcc accepts -pedantic... yes
checking if gcc accepts -Werror=unknown-warning-option... no
checking if gcc accepts -Wpedantic-ms-format... no
checking if gcc accepts -Wc90-c99-compat... yes
checking if gcc accepts -Wlong-long... yes
checking if gcc accepts -Werror=implicit... yes
checking if gcc accepts -Werror=missing-braces... yes
checking if gcc accepts -Werror=return-type... yes
checking if gcc accepts -Werror=trigraphs... yes
checking if gcc accepts -Werror=pointer-arith... yes
checking if gcc accepts -Werror=strict-prototypes... no
checking if gcc accepts -Werror=missing-prototypes... yes
checking if gcc accepts -Werror=missing-declarations... yes
checking if gcc accepts -Werror=comment... yes
checking if gcc accepts -Werror=vla... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating doc/Makefile
config.status: creating config/config.h
config.status: executing default-1 commands
gcc -c -g -O3 -fwrapv -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -fno-common -Werror=attributes -W -Wall -pedantic -Wc90-c99-compat -Wno-long-long -Werror=implicit -Werror=missing-braces -Werror=return-type -Werror=trigraphs -Werror=pointer-arith -Werror=missing-prototypes -Werror=missing-declarations -Werror=comment -Werror=vla -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I./include -I./include -I./x86 -I./x86 -I./asm -I./asm -I./disasm -I./disasm -I./output -I./output -o asm/nasm.o asm/nasm.c
In file included from ./include/nasm.h:46,
                from asm/nasm.c:47:
./include/nasmlib.h:194:1: error: ‘pure’ attribute on function returning ‘void’ [-Werror=attributes]
void pure_func seg_init(void);
^~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [Makefile:75: asm/nasm.o] Error 1
```

how can a build this? disable warnings as errors somehow or? idk
please and thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

nasm-2.13.03 has issues with gcc 8. The [nasm instructions on the wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu#NASM) has been updated to use nasm-2.14.02 (as of this answer) which will work for your gcc version.

So just reload the wiki page and try the nasm section again.

Alternatively, use the nasm package from the Ubuntu repo and skip the nasm section. You can do this because your distro is using a recent nasm. Users of older distros may have to compile, but I'm not sure what the minimum supported nasm is (but consider it to be ≥ 2.13 because that's what x264 requires).